# Can I store a struct in a Coldfusion session variable?

Tags: session, data-structures, coldfusion

I'm passing a struct to a CF Custom Tag. I'd like the CFM page that is this custom tag to assign this struct to a dynamically created session variable. Creating the session variable works when assigning it to a simple value such as a number, but fails when assigning it to the struct in the way I'm doing it below.

```
<cfset Evaluate("SESSION.myVar#ATTRIBUTES.count# = #ATTRIBUTES.myStruct#")>
```

I thought this was possible, but when I try to do so I get an error:
    *Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.*

This is how the struct is created:

```
<cfset testStruct = StructNew()>
<cfset testStruct.something = 2>
```

And passed through the custom tag:

```
<cf_myTag myStruct="#testStruct#" count="#i#">
```

I think the Evaluate portion is messing things up here.

Comment: Could you show us more code? Perhaps where you create/set the Struct, and where you pass it to the Custom Tag. There may be an issue with how you are executing the code.

Comment: Are you sure that error is thrown from that cfset line??  It is possible to store a struct in the Session scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Leigh says, use array notation rather than Evaluate() to create your dynamically named session variable:

```
<cfset SESSION[ "myVar" & ATTRIBUTES.count ] = ATTRIBUTES.myStruct>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can,

Just use the duplicate method

```
<cfset SESSION.myVar = duplicate(ATTRIBUTES.myStruct) />
```

Comment: Why would he need to use duplicated()?

Comment: The problem here is that the session variable name needs to be dynamic: myVarN not just myVar.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can just do the following:
note I'm using a cflock here to avoid any potential race conditions.

```
<cflock scope="session" throwontimeout="true" timeout="5" type="exclusive">
  <cfset session["myVar" & ATTRIBUTES.count] = attributes.myStruct />
</cflock>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue above is the evaluate statement.  It's trying to evaulate the structure as a simple value in the string, and then evaluate the string.

You can get around evaulate entirely.  The reason is you want a dynamically named session variable?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Evaluate for the dynamically named session variable. That's the only way I know to do it. Do you know how I could construct this to work with the struct assignment?

Comment: Using associative array notation. See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fb2.html and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSf01dbd23413dda0e-2a6ba8891200fcc8c06-7ffd.html .